# Asterisk 13 ARI not firing "ChannelTalkingStart" events

Tags: asterisk, phpari

I have Asterisk 13 configured and debugging all received events, but I can't get it to fire a `ChannelTalkingStart` event.  If I press tones on my phone it does fire `ChannelDtmfReceived`, so I know it can sorta hear me.

Is there something special I have to do to receive talking events?  I'm trying to detect silence and react accordingly.  (What WaitForSilence(1.5) used to do)

Update: I think it has something to do with https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_TALK_DETECT  I tried adding this to the extension, but it didn't make a difference:

```
exten => 1002     ,1,NoOp()
 same =>           n,Set(TALK_DETECT(set)=1000,1500)
 same =>           n,Statis(MyApp)
 same =>           n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those using PHPARI.org, it is:

```php
$this->phpariObject->channels()->channel_set_variable($this->stasisChannelID, 'TALK_DETECT(set)', '1000,1500');
```

Basically, talk detection is off until you specifically turn it on. You may want to adjust the 1000,1500 to better fit your purposes.

See [Asterisk Documentation — TALK_DETECT()](https://docs.asterisk.org/Asterisk_18_Documentation/API_Documentation/Dialplan_Functions/TALK_DETECT/) for reference.

Comment: Yup! Talk detection requires additional processing overhead (can't use native bridging, have to pass the media through a DSP, etc.) - hence, you have to enable it with that channel function. Glad it worked once you found the right docs!